# Cut or Split a string in python

Tags: python, string

I can't get this straight for some reason. 
I have a string that's something like that when the py script prints out the output (had to hide some info):

```
<input name="submit" onclick="var srvstr='Friday 4th of May 2018';someweb(srvstr);document.someemail.securitystring.value='';return false;" src="images/button-submit.png" type="image"/>
```

I would like to get only `Friday 4th of May 2018` from the string. What would be the easiest or best way of achieving this?
I scrolled through some old docs on here, and tried to replicate it similarly, I think cutting and slicing is the most confusing for me. Thanks

Comment: Is your string this HTML `<input>` tag, or some complete HTML page that includes this tag? If so, I'd use an HTML parser first, to get the `onclick` attribute, and only then look at parsing the fragment of (already-quote-escaped, easy-to-deal-with) JavaScript code in that attribute's value.

Comment: If you've done that, it could be as simple as a regex like `srvstr='(.*?)'`.

Comment: Will you always be looking for that string literal? If so, then could just call `str.find('Friday 4th of May 2018')` on it, and if it found it, then done. You can pass that `'Friday...'` string along. I'm guessing though it's a different string each day...

Comment: @abarnert I have used bs4 and lxml parser. It is a little bit tricky to parse it into text only too. `<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="tcenter">
<input onClick="var srvstr='Friday 4th of May 2018';someweb(srvstr);document.someemail.securitystring.value='';return false;" name="submit" type="image" src="images/button-submit.png" />
</td>
</tr>`

Comment: @pushkin yes, It changes every day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're getting this out of BeautifulSoup, you're probably doing something like this to get the `input` tag:

```
>>> str(tr.input)
'<input name="submit" onclick="var srvstr=\'Friday 4th of May 2018\';someweb(srvstr);document.someemail.securitystring.value=\'\';return false;" src="images/button-submit.png" type="image"/>'
```

Instead, let BS4 parse it all the way down to the `onclick` attribute value:

```
>>> tr.input['onclick']
"var srvstr='Friday 4th of May 2018';someweb(srvstr);document.someemail.securitystring.value='';return false;"
```

Sure, it's still messy, but it's not *quite* as bad—and, more to the point, we know it's Javascript code quoted to fit into HTML. So we know what can and can't be in it without escaping, so we don't have to worry about a lot of stuff that would otherwise probably never happen but you can't be sure (and therefore will definitely happen 15 minutes after you deploy and go to sleep).

```
>>> re.search(r"srvstr='(.*?)'", tr.input['onclick'])
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 35), match="srvstr='Friday 4th of May 2018'">
>>> re.search(r"srvstr='(.*?)'", tr.input['onclick']).group(1)
'Friday 4th of May 2018'
```

Now we don't have to reverse-engineer their date format and hope we got it right; it's just whatever string they're putting in that `srvstr` variable. (Although if you actually want to parse this into a `datetime` object or something…)

Of course you can never guarantee anything for sure with parsing other people's text, but it seems very likely that if this ever stops working, it'll be because they've completely changed the way they do their `onclick` handler, in which case this code should fail badly with an exception rather than start producing garbage.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. As much as I don't like js, I will test it out today, and play with the settings and see what happens

Comment: @uzdisral Yeah, I assumed you didn't want to actually parse (or, worse, interpret) the JS as JS. That's why I parsed it with just a simple regex that will hopefully work as the string changes day to day, but break immediately if they completely rewrite their JS code generator.

Comment: I would send you the code and page to see what I did and how, but I can't post it on here, just for some reason :)